# Lattice energy of NaCl and MgCl [sic]

Tags: physical-chemistry

In an exam paper it says that the lattice energy of NaCl is more exothermic than MgCl [sic] as the Na+ cation has a smaller ionic radius than Mg+.
Here are the resources given:[image][image]

What is the reasoning for for Na+ having a smaller ionic radius even though Mg+ has a higher proton number?

Comment: Mg+ is not a thing at all.

Comment: It was part of a CIE A - level chemistry exam

Comment: I'd agree with Ivan. You must be making a mistake. It should be $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ and $\ce{MgCl2}$.

Comment: In the exam I think it was asked as hypothetical situation, so hypothetically how would you reason the ionic radius of Mg+?

Comment: We wouldn't. It makes no sense.

Comment: Ive added the resources given by the exam paper if that helps? Im sorry if this is a waste of time.

Comment: OK, then I guess you are supposed to answer that Mg+ is bigger than Na+ because of that lone 3s electron, pretty much for the same reason why Na (neutral atom) is bigger than Ne.

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you very much, that makes some sense to me and thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Then again, Mg2+ is smaller than Na+ (same electrons, more protons).

Comment: That is the exact train of thought that confused me, but the Mg2+ ion does not have the the 3s shell whereas the Mg+ ion does?

Comment: Hypothetically it is like that a real object is travelling at more than the speed of light. It's not meant anyway

Comment: When Na+ is made, the whole 3s shell is empty hence you radius is till 2p. But in Mg+ you have one electron in 3s orbital and your radius is still till 3s which makes it longer than Na+.

Answer (score 3):

We actually do mean $\ce{Mg^+}$ here.  The idea is to show what factors are involved when an alkaline earth metal forms stable compounds with $\ce{M^{2+}}$ ions whereas an alkali metal favors $\ce{M^+}$.  In this case, as pointed out in some of the comments, $\ce{Mg^+}$ is bulked up by the electron that remains in the relatively diffuse, loosely held $3s$ subshell.  You need to remove that electron, making $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$, to get a compact ion that gives good lattice energies in ionic crystals.

**Scandium monosulfide**

Although $\ce{MgCl}$ and monatomic $\ce{Mg^+}$ are not real materials, the case of [scandium monosulfude, $\ce{ScS}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandium_monosulfide) is instructive. A simple ionic model proposing $\ce{Sc^{2+}}$ and $\ce{S^{2-}}$ would require the scandium to retain a valence electron in an outer-shell orbital, apparently $3d$. In an early-group metal such orbitals are diffuse and, if occupied, would inhibit tight binding of the oppositely charged ions. Instead, according to Ref. [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50019a004) which identifies $\ce{ScS}$ as a metallic conductor, the extra electron per scandium atom is delocalized into a conduction band. This allows the sulfide ions to bind tightly with compact $\ce{Sc^{3+}}$. Thus scandium monosulfide is stable not as a conventional ionic salt, but as a compound that combines ionic and metallic characteristics.

**Reference**

Dismukes, J. P.; White, J. G. (1964). "The Preparation, Properties, and Crystal Structures of Some Scandium Sulfides in the Range Sc2S3-ScS". *Inorg. Chem.* **3** (9): 1220–1228. https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50019a004

Comment: Just out of interest Magnesium(I) compounds are known, but they are of the form [Mg-Mg]2+ rather than a bare Mg+ - so more like Mercury than Sodium. See https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2011/dt/c0dt01831g#!divAbstract , and in a way this furthers the similarity between Mg and Zn.

Comment: Not just magnesium.  Wikipedia also documents similar dimers for other alkaline earth metals.  Such dimers, of course, are easily oxidized to +2 monatomic ions.